# $\operatorname{Hom}(R\times R,M)$ isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(R,M) \times\operatorname{ Hom}(R,M)$

Tags: modules

If $M$ is a right $R$-module, then $\operatorname{Hom}(R \times R,M)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Hom}(R,M) \times \operatorname{Hom}(R,M)$

My questions are:

1. What is the isomorphism map?
   (I tried this $f\to(f_1,f_2)$ where $f_1(r) =f(r,0)$ and $f_2(r)=f(0,r)$. Is it correct?)
2. Can we make this natural group isomorphism a right $D$-module isomorphism,
   where $D=\operatorname{End}(R\times R)$ is set of all right $R$-homomorphisms from $R \times R$ to $R\times R$?

Comment: Do like this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) More generally, if $X$ and $Y$ are $R$-modules, you have
$$
\operatorname{Hom}(X\oplus Y,M)\cong
\operatorname{Hom}(X,M)\oplus\operatorname{Hom}(Y,M)
$$
(in module theory it's more customary $\oplus$ rather than $\times$, but they mean the same).

The (group) isomorphism is obtained by considering the canonical injections $i\colon X\to X\oplus Y$ and $j\colon Y\to X\oplus Y$ defined by
$$
i(x)=(x,0),\quad j(y)=(0,y)
$$
and sending $f\colon X\oplus Y\to M$ to the pair $(f\circ i,f\circ j)$, which is exactly what you did.

(2) Hint: the endomorphism ring of $R\oplus R$ is the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices over $R$. What would be the action?